# Connect PHP with SAP Database

Tags: php, database, saprfc

So, I already followed all the steps below for `saprfc` windows installation.

```
1) Extract zip file saprfc-$VERSION$-$PHP_VERSION$.zip
2) Copy php-saprfc.dll to your extensions directory (e.g. C:\PHP\extensions)
3) Edit php.ini file (in windows system dircetory, e.g. C:\WINNT, C:\WINDOWS)
         and add line: 'extension=php_saprfc.dll'
4) Copy librfc32.dll (from SAPGUI install CD) to the windows system
         directory or simple install SAPGUI on your machine.
```

Another source said we will we need SAP SDK. Is it really needed for Windows? 
Also, will it be possible to code PHP connect to SAP in a computer that doesn't have SAP program? Or we only can do those installations in computer that has SAP application?

Then after the installation, what do I have to do next? I am trying to do steps below, yet still confused....

```
  1) Extract php sources to C:\PHP-x.y.z
  2) Extract php win support files to C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32
  3) Install RFCSDK to C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk
  4) Copy SAPRFC sources to C:\PHP-x.y.z\ext\saprfc
  5) Copy php4ts.lib or php5ts.lib (from PHP binaries) to C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32
  6) For PHP5 copy saprfc.dsp5 to saprfc.dsp
  6) Open project C:\PHP-x.y.z\ext\saprfc\saprfc.dsp in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0
  7) Under Tools|Option|Directory set path for Include files and for Library files
     (C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32\include; C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk\include;
      C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32\lib; C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk\lib)
  8) Set active configuration to "saprfc - Windows_TS" (under Build menu)
  9) Build php_saprfc.dll.
  10) Compiled DLL you find in C:\PHP-x.y.z\Release_TS directory
```

Where to get PHP sources, PHP win support, and how to compile the program?

Sorry, I am totally new to this. Looking for the answers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Building "windows extensions" is explained in general here:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

There is also explained which version of VS you need for which PHP version.

I also tried to build the sapnwrfc extension for PHP 5.5 on windows, but failed at some part...my progress/documentation is here:
https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc/issues/6

Maybe you can progress further :-)